# How do I make docker to run one script only once and the other everytime?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I want to run init.js(which will populate the mongo database) only once during the initial build and run 'app.js' everytime 'docker compose up' command is given 
My directory looks like this :

- backend/init.js
- app.js

**My dockerfile :**

FROM node:alpine 
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm","start"]

Currently npm start performs only 'node app.js' . If someone else pulls my repo and hits 'docker compose up' is there anyway to run 'init.js' only once and 'app.js' every single time?

Comment: If you attach a volume to the container, it can remember state by writing it to a file on that volume.  Or you could make your script smarter by having it check to see if the database is already populated (database keeps the state of whether or not it is populated.)

Comment: I would advice to make the process of database initialization idempotent.

Comment: Is there a way you can tell if the database has already initialized; how do you know it's the "first time"?  Can you include that logic in the script?